# covert json into dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, json, dictionary

i am try to convert this json data into dictionary but I can't please help me.

```
 {
     "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
     "homeMobileNetworkCode": 260,
     "radioType": "gsm",
     "carrier": "T-Mobile",
     "cellTowers": [
      {
       "cellId": 39627456,
       "locationAreaCode": 40495,
       "mobileCountryCode": 310,
       "mobileNetworkCode": 260,
       "age": 0,
       "signalStrength": -95
      }
     ],
     "wifiAccessPoints": [
      {
       "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
       "signalStrength": 8,
       "age": 0,
       "signalToNoiseRatio": -65,
       "channel": 8
      },
      {
       "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AC",
       "signalStrength": 4,
       "age": 0
      }
     ]
    }
```

I know only to convert from Dictionary to JSON like this

```
NSMutableDictionary * location = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [location setValue:mobileCountryCode forKey:@"mobileCountryCode"];
    [location setValue:mobileNetworkCode forKey:@"mobileNetworkCode"];
    [location setValue:cellId forKey:@"cellId"];
    [location setValue:locationAreaCode forKey:@"locationAreaCode"]; 


 NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestbodyInputDict options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"jsonString.....%@",jsonString);
                NSData *requestBody = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

so please help me how to revers this process how to handle this.

Comment: What's your issue exactly? What's not working?

Comment: ` String jsondata = "{\n" +
                "  \"homeMobileCountryCode\": \""+mmc+"\",\n" +
                "  \"homeMobileNetworkCode\":\""+ mnc+"\",\n" +

                "  \"cellTowers\": [\n" +
                "    { \n\"cellId\": \""+cid+"\",\"locationAreaCode\": \""+lac+"\",\"mobileCountryCode\": \""+mmc+"\",\"mobileNetworkCode\": \""+mnc+"\"} " +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"wifiAccessPoints\": [\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}"; ` 
this is code in android for json data i want to write this code in ios

Comment: i want json string for this and json dictionary both. @Larme

Comment: with your raw string replace " with \" it will work

Answer (score 2):

Just check this code. It will convert your json to NSdictionary

```
   NSString *jsonString = @"{ \"homeMobileCountryCode\": 310, \"homeMobileNetworkCode\": 260, \"radioType\": \"gsm\", \"carrier\": \"T-Mobile\", \"cellTowers\": [ { \"cellId\": 39627456, \"locationAreaCode\": 40495, \"mobileCountryCode\": 310, \"mobileNetworkCode\": 260, \"age\": 0, \"signalStrength\": -95 } ], \"wifiAccessPoints\": [ { \"macAddress\": \"01:23:45:67:89:AB\", \"signalStrength\": 8, \"age\": 0, \"signalToNoiseRatio\": -65, \"channel\": 8 } ] }";

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
```

Use String replace method to replace " with \"  it will work

Comment: Need any help then let me know

Comment: i don't have json string also ... :(   @anil

Comment: then what you have dictionary or NSData

Comment: i have only `{
     "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
     "homeMobileNetworkCode": 260,
     "radioType": "gsm",
     "carrier": "T-Mobile",
     "cellTowers": [
      {
       "cellId": 39627456,
       "locationAreaCode": 40495,
       "mobileCountryCode": 310,
       "mobileNetworkCode": 260,
       "age": 0,
       "signalStrength": -95
      }
     ],
     "wifiAccessPoints": [
      {
       "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
       "signalStrength": 8,
       "age": 0,
       "signalToNoiseRatio": -65,
       "channel": 8
      }
     ]
    }`

Comment: i want to write a string like this in ios `String jsondata = "{\n" + " \"homeMobileCountryCode\": \""+mmc+"\",\n" + " \"homeMobileNetworkCode\":\""+ mnc+"\",\n" + " \"cellTowers\": [\n" + " { \n\"cellId\": \""+cid+"\",\"locationAreaCode\": \""+lac+"\",\"mobileCountryCode\": \""+mmc+"\",\"mobileNetworkCode\": \""+mnc+"\"} " + " ],\n" + " \"wifiAccessPoints\": [\n" + " ]\n" + "}";`

Comment: Buddy this is json string.You can check.Just go to http://json.parser.online.fr/   and paste this string. You will find json.Just do one thing check my answer I am editing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103594/discussion-between-anil-solanki-and-anup-gupta).

Comment: So what are you missing? Is it string concatenation?!

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is you are directly accessing the "mobileCountryCode", "mobileNetworkCode" and so on.. which are element of json array "cellTowers" so if you want those values you can first have an array of "cellTowers" and there you go...

Comment: i want to find the location of cell tower. for searching

Comment: you can get an array of cell tower and then you can get the location as the location area code is in celltowers array so first you'll have to get an array/dictionary of celltowers then you can get the location

Comment: i have the cell id,lac,mnc and mcc so i want to find only one location by searching. for this i have create 4 text box.

Comment: i want to create a dictionary of this 
`{
  "cellTowers": [
    {
      "cellId": 21532831,
      "locationAreaCode": 2862,
      "mobileCountryCode": 214,
      "mobileNetworkCode": 7
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: with your raw string replace " with \" it will work @anupgupta